# Flutter - How to find IP of device that connect to mobile hotspot

Tags: flutter

I want to get the IP of a device that connects to my mobile hotspot with a specific SSID.
If there is no device with a specific SSID in the hotspot, I'll show a "No connection" snackbar.
Else I will use the IP for fetching data from the device.

I tried "ping_discover_network" in the android emulator, It works fine, but got errors when I tried it on an actual mobile phone.

```
  final String ip = await Wifi.ip;
  final String subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.'));
  final int port = 80;
  print("i'm working, IP: $ip");
  final stream = NetworkAnalyzer.discover2(subnet, port);
  stream.listen((NetworkAddress addr) {
    if (addr.exists) {
      print('Found device: ${addr.ip}');
    }
  });
```

```
Restarted application in 2,034ms.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result.success(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at com.ly.wifi.WifiDelegate.launchIP(WifiDelegate.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at com.ly.wifi.WifiDelegate.getIP(WifiDelegate.java:128)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at com.ly.wifi.WifiPlugin.onMethodCall(WifiPlugin.java:55)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.ly.com/wifi(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
E/DartMessenger(16540): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger(16540): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:139)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:253)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/DartMessenger(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
I/flutter (16540): i'm working, IP: ....
F/OIC_SRM_DOXM(18502): UpdatePersistentStorage failed!
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ip/flutter_ip.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _internalIP = 'Unknown';
  String _externalIP = 'Unknown';
  String _networkType = "Unknown";
  Color _typeColor = Colors.yellow;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _updateNetworkInformation();
  }

  Future<void> _updateInternalIP() async {
    String ip;
    try {
      ip = await FlutterIp.internalIP;
    } on PlatformException {
      ip = 'Failed to get ip.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _internalIP = ip;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _updateExternalIP() async {
    String ip;
    try {
      ip = await FlutterIp.externalIP;
    } on PlatformException {
      ip = 'Failed to get ip.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _externalIP = ip;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _updateNetworkType() async {
    String networkType;
    try {
      networkType = await FlutterIp.networkType;
    } on PlatformException {
      networkType = 'Failed to get network type.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _networkType = networkType;
      switch (_networkType) {
        case 'wired':
          {
            _typeColor = Colors.yellow;
            break;
          }
        case 'wifi':
          {
            _typeColor = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5);
            break;
          }
        case 'cellular':
          {
            _typeColor = Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5);
            break;
          }
        default:
          {
            _typeColor = Colors.transparent;
            break;
          }
      }
    });
  }

  _updateNetworkInformation() {
    _updateInternalIP();
    _updateExternalIP();
    _updateNetworkType();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Flutter Plugin',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.0)),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text('flutter_ip',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: InkWell(
          onTap: _updateNetworkInformation,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Internal IP',
                  style: titleStyle,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, top: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_internalIP\n',
                    style: resultStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'External IP',
                  style: titleStyle,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, top: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_externalIP\n',
                    style: resultStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Network',
                  style: titleStyle,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, top: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_networkType\n',
                    style: resultStyle.copyWith(backgroundColor: _typeColor),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

TextStyle titleStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
  letterSpacing: 0.5,
);
TextStyle resultStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black,
  fontSize: 30,
);
```

Dont Forget to Add this to your pubspc.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter_ip: ^0.2.0
```

Comment: It throw MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getInternalIP on channel flutter_ip).  Does it support android?

Comment: check the import , make sure you have imported the correct package , it will work on android